# java - how reflect a long running workflow process in GUI?

Tags: java, python, swing, user-interface, event-dispatch-thread

I have a workflow of functions that eventually lead to a deployment of something.
the steps are as followed:

1. run a python script the produces some output.
2. run a bash script that copies this output to a given location
3. run a bash script (depending on the output of 1,2) that runs a java program (running make take few hours)
4. run another bash script on this output - final step

i want to be able to initiate this workflow from a GUI giving a set of parameters.

Then, I want to be able to get status reports of each step - so that the running user will know which step is currently running.

The main issue here is that each of the steps  may take long time to finish. 
My experience with developing GUI in java is limited.

Any advice on the direction I should go to?

Comment: can you comment on why would you use GUI for this, and why java?

Comment: have you look into Jython? that can help you running the python con within java. The copy can also be achieve with java, which can lead to the elimination of the second script. The third and last script which only starts hava can also be managed by your UI. With all the pieces in java you can now just create a state machine that is  started within the gui.

Comment: I would use GUI becuase I want it to be user-interactive..
Java because, well, its a langauge i'm familiar with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to write this in Java, then you should try to find a good wizard library. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88889/recommend-a-java-wizard-library) question for some details.

Then, if at all possible that your scripts provide some feedback like the percentage of the operation completed then you could have a `JProgressBar` for each step independently and an overall one to show the user an idea of how much is done at any moment.